# Get Email Id from StripeCheckout.configure Stripe Payment Integration with Angular 10

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am new to use Stripe. I have integrated it with Angular 10. with every successful transaction a tocken is generated. I want the email Id which the user enters while entering the card details. how can I get that email Id. Can anyone please help me with this

```
var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_51IaUAYSIY',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (token: any) {
        console.log(token)
        alert('Token Created!!');
      }
    });
```

Comment: It's returned in that `token` object the callback receives , see https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout#required (token.email)

Comment: Note that this is an old/deprecated Stripe product though and you shouldn't be using it.